# use whereclause within a if condition

Tags: excel, vba

I have 5  string parameter A,B,C,D,E, and I want to use them as a condition in a IF statement.

I also have 5 local variable, to match the parameters

The problem is, I don't know whether any of them is empty string. If it is empty string , I don't want them to be use in the if condition

```
Private Function XX(A As String, B As String, C As String, D As String, E As String) As Long

Dim AA As String
Dim BB As String
Dim CC As String
Dim DD As String
Dim EE As String

If A = AA && B = BB && C = CC & D = DD & E = EE Then
.....
End If
```

I know a whereclause in sql can do it, like:

```
Dim Whereclause As String
IF B is NULL Then
whereclause = " WHERE AA = " + A + "AND C = " + C + "AND D = " + 
D ....
```

But seems I can't put it into an IF statement, as the query itself is a string.

Is there anyways to use in the IF condition? I don't need to connect DB, just want to check records in a excel sheet with the rows matching all the parameter

Thanks very much for helping~~

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could use a helper function

```
Function OkParameter(par As String, locVar As String) As Boolean
    OkParameter = IIf(par = "", True, par = locVar)
End Function
```

to be included in your code as follows:

```
Private Function XX(A As String, B As String, C As String, D As String, E As String) As Long

    Dim AA As String
    Dim BB As String
    Dim CC As String
    Dim DD As String
    Dim EE As String

    If OkParameter(A, AA) And OkParameter(B, BB) And OkParameter(C, CC) And OkParameter(D, DD) And OkParameter(E, EE) Then

    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Great Thanks!! really appreciate it. I don't think of a solution like this until now~~ Thanks again!

Comment: you are welcome. if my answer solved your question you may want to mark it as accepted. thank you